# is it a good style to compare strings this way?

Tags: c++, comparison, operator-overloading, c-strings, c++17

I have this in mind to use in a `.cpp` file:

```
namespace
{
    bool operator==(char const* const a, char const* const b) noexcept
    {
        return !::std::strcmp(a, b);
    }
}
```

Is this good style?

EDIT:

I think the tasteful c++1z way, that accomplishes the same thing, would be to use the new `std::string_view` class for comparisons.

Comment: That's purely opinion based, but I was at least once confused by such a construct. IMHO, `strcmp(a, b) == 0` is better.

Comment: Does this compile at all? IIRC you can't provide operator overloads for intrinsic types.

Comment: I would use `!std::strcmp(a, b)` as is rather than try to hide it in a construct that people are unfamiliar with. Using `==` with `const char*` that way would change the semantics. That's probably why it's illegal.

Comment: Before you ask things on StackOverflow, at least try it.  This question shows insufficient research effort, because the "style" question concerns **code that cannot compile**: downvoted.

Comment: @Yakk I can't delete it. You can do it, if you can.

Comment: @user1095108 You can *fix* it.  Look at the answer.  Produce a good question that matches that answer.  You asked a style question.  Instead describe your poblem.  Then ask a question about how to solve the problem, show what you tried, give the error saying what went wrong.  Not a style question (which is opinion based), shows research effort instead of showing the opposite, doesn't make existing answers obsolete.

Comment: @Yakk I prefer to delete a question if the community doesn't like it. I can't delete this one though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't [overload operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Overloaded_operators) which doesn't take `class` or `enum` as its operands, which means you can't change the behavior they work with build-in types.

> When an operator appears in an expression, and at least one of its operands has a class type or an enumeration type, then overload resolution is used to determine the user-defined function to be called among all the functions whose signatures match the following:

I'll suggest you to use [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) intead of `char*`, which provide [operator==](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp). Then you can avoid using of `std::strcmp()`, and such kind of c-style string functions at all. If you do need a c-style string, you can use [std::basic_string::c_str()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) to convert it back when necessary.

Comment: sometimes you can't avoid using char const*. If you need to use a third-party library, for example.

Comment: you could write a dummy class with a conversion constructor from `char const*`, I suppose.

Comment: @user1095108 You can use `c_str()` on `std::string` when necessary.

Comment: @user1095108 Or just use what Galik said in their comment. That's preferrable IMO.

Comment: This C++ FAQ states more clearly that indeed this operator overload is not possible: http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/yechiel/c++-faq/intrinsics-and-operator-overloading.html.